# Remote interpreter wrapped inside script for pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter, slurm

Is it possible to wrap the standard python interpreter inside a bash script or similar, so the interpreter is called within slurm or any other program, and this script can be used as a remote interpreter in PyCharm?

The situation is I need to call the python interpreter remotely using slurm (and not as standalone), with a command like:

srun ---mem=10G python

A simple script doesn't seem to do the job. I can use remotely the python interpreter without slurm in PyCharm, but I need to use it within slurm. I've also tried to do it within PyCharm, but I haven't managed to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are you finding with this command: `srun ---mem=10G python` ?

Comment: Interpreter 'srun  --mem=10G $HOME/anaconda2/bin/python' doesn't exist on remote server. The problem is not running python with slurm, but using the remote interpreter tool from whithin pycharm and using slurm.